# How can I limit the CPU usage of moviepy?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

Python 3. I am using moviepy to create a new video. The problem is ffmpeg uses 100% of all my cores so I can't do anything else in the computer.
There is a parameter for write_videofile called threads but when I adjust it to, say, threads=10 (I have 12 cores in total) there is no difference.
I even tried invoking the script using cpulimit (cpulimit -l 70 python my_script.py, for instance) but then the script simply doesn't work, it just freezes, no error message. 
Is there a way I can force moviepy not to use all the cores in the CPU or is there any application (like cpulimit) that would actually work ?

Comment: Can you please post a simple executable code sample that reproduces problem?